# Python: Downloading files served through content-disposition

Tags: python, selenium, download, http-headers

I am looking for the quickest way to download a file from a remove server using python. The catch here is that I don't have a direct link to the file (e.g. example.com/document1.pdf) but the file is being force-downloaded by using a content-disposition header in an html page.

I am trying to download publicly available pdfs from this website: http://www.et.gr/idocs-nph/search/fekForm.html

Right now my solution is accessing the download page using `selenium` and then renaming the file after it has been saved on my computer, which takes a lot of time. I am wondering if there is a better way, something that doesn't require webdrivers and that downloads the remote file that's being served in each page a lot faster.

Something that looks like:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('www.example.com/download.html')
headers = response.headers;
# Do something with content-disposition header to download the file
```

Comment: `doesn't require webdrivers` then why hashtag `selenium`?

Comment: I tagged `selenium` because it may well be that what I am looking for can't be done that way and `selenium` (or another web automation tool) is the only way to go.

Comment: Update the Question accordingly